# Update causing an issue

Tags: windows-10, updates, libreoffice, norton-antivirus, norton-internet-security

My Bullguard security system was recently bought over by Norton and the changeover was fine. Norton informed me that my Libre Office program was in need of an update. I clicked on 'Update' and my Libre Office was updated from version 6. (sorry, don't know the exact older version) to 7.3.
Thing is, now my Libre Office will not even start up and I cannot open any of my saved Libre documents. I've tried System Restore but the Libre Office update is not even listed there and so I cannot restore to a point before the update. My O.S. is Windows 10. Anyone any ideas ?

Comment: What happens if you download and install the latest version of Libre Office yourself? https://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Alternatively older versions can be downloaded at https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/ which is linked from the "old versions" link towards the bottom of https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/

Comment: You have two options, reinstall the current version of Libre Office, or reinstall the version of Libre Office you know worked last.  In the future don't update critical programs, just because Norton Secuirty, indicated there is an update. Norton Security serves a purpose but handling third-party application updates isn't one it does well.

Comment: I downloaded and installed version 7.3 of Libre Office and everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks to all who helped.